# How to get the value of id(primary key) in previous operation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, lastinsertid

I am using MySQL. I need to insert one row into a table first, then I need to get the id of the inserted row. The code looks somewhat like the following:

```
insert into mytable (column2, column3, column4) values('value2','value3','value4')or die(mysql_error());
```

> Column1

is the

> primary key

and it is auto-increment. So how to get the value of

> column1

in the previous operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).  From the docs:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function :

> Retrieves the ID generated for an
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the previous
>   query (usually INSERT).

Or [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), depending on which extension you use to access your MySQL database.